# I have a dataset whose columns are words. How can I add the same columns to each other?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset whose features are words. These words like "see", "saw", "go, "play" etc. And I try to do some preprocessing like stemming in columns. I want to add the same or same meaning columns to each other and then drop the adding column. Like below

For example, I have a dataset like,

```
   see  go  see
0   0   0    1
1   2   1    3
2   0   1    1
3   0   0    0
```

and I want to add one "see" to another "see", and drop one of them, like below,

```
   see  go  
0   1   0    
1   5   1    
2   1   1    
3   0   0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `nlp` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()



   go  see
0   0    1
1   1    5
2   1    1
3   0    0
```

Comment: Happy it was of help

Answer (score 2):

You could use [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
res = df.stack().groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum().unstack()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   go  see
0   0    1
1   1    5
2   1    1
3   0    0
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! but could you please explain a little bit?